# Unhandled Exception Sort Recursion

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion

I'm having an issue with a recursive sorting assignment in C++. Unfortunately, we've been assigned to do it in a very specific way, but I cannot seem to manage to get it to do what I want, and since I'm not used to recursion, I can't follow it well to trouble shoot. The error that I'm getting is `Unhandled exception at 0x77d915fe in SortFinal.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.` Presumably this is coming somehow from the `a[]` array used within the sort function. I'm new to this site so forgive me if the organization is terrible, but here's my code as it currently stands:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// prototypes
void sort(int a[], int i, int j);

int main() {
    int x[4] = {3, 1, 5, 2};

    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        cout << x[count] << ": ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    sort(x, 0, 4);

    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        cout << x[count] << ": ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void sort(int a[], int i, int j) {
    int first;
    if (j > i) {
        int index = i + 1;
        bool done = false;
        first = a[i];
        sort(a, i + 1, j);
        for (!done && index <= j; index++;) {
            if (first < a[index]) {

                a[index - 1] = a[index];
            } else {
                a[index - 1] = first;
                done = true;
            }
        }

        if (!done && index > j) {
            a[index - 1] = first;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line with the problem is: `for (!done && index <= j; index++;) {` in the for loop the first block is **initialization**, the second **stop condition** and the third is **increment**, in you case you are putting **stop condition** as **initialization** and **increment** as **stop condition**, changed by `for (; !done && index <= j; index++) {`. Please take always good look before posting in SO. Any compiler (and I mean ANY) would catch this error with a error message good enough for you to figure out the problem. In GCC 4.9.1 was:

```
E:\test.cpp: In function 'void sort(int*, int, int)':
E:\test.cpp:34:20: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
         for (!done && index <= j; index++;) {
                    ^
```

Compile always with all warnings enable (**-Wall** in GCC and Clang, select at least **level 4** in Visual C++), the compiler would help you to fix a lot (valid code that are bugs).

Comment: Thanks. I feel incredibly dumb. I'll be more careful next time before posting.